# structure initialization for xh711 issue

Tags: c, struct, initialization, typedef, esp32

I am building a program for Xh711 on esp32. I have defined a a struct and i am trying to initialize it. I am getting the next error.

> could not convert '{GPIO_NUM_18, GPIO_NUM_19, 0, 1, 1, GAIN64, 0, -1,
> storm->ad_str_t::smoothed, storm->ad_str_t::sampling,
> storm->ad_str_t::timerHandle}' from '' to 'ad_xh711_handle_t'

```
void str_init_Xh711(ad_str_t *storm){
    
    printf("Starting xh711...\n");
    ad_xh711_handle_t xh711={  
        .dout= GPIO_NUM_18,
        .scl= GPIO_NUM_19,
        .offset = 0,
        .calibrationFactor = 1,//NULL,
        .conversionFactor=1,
        .gainValue= Gain::GAIN64,
        .rawData =0,//NULL,
        .value = -1,
        .smoothed =storm->smoothed,
        .sampling =storm->sampling,
        .timerHandle = storm->timerHandle
    };

    xh711_init(&xh711,Gain::GAIN64);

    
}

typedef struct {
    gpio_num_t dout;
    gpio_num_t scl;
    int32_t offset = 0;
    double calibrationFactor;
    double conversionFactor=1;
    
    Gain gainValue;
    int32_t rawData;
    double value = -1;
    bool smoothed;
    uint8_t sampling;
    esp_timer_handle_t timerHandle;
}ad_xh711_handle_t;
```

Comment: *double conversionFactor=1;* inside `ad_xh711_handle_t` !?

Comment: i was thinking about some default values

Comment: hmmm default values in typedef can not exist

Comment: `xh711_init(&xh711,Gain::GAIN64` it is not C only C++. You need to use G++ to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

default values in typedef can not work and have to be removed